# Running code when all threads are finished processing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

**Quick note**: Java and Android noob here, I'm open to you telling me I'm stupid (as long as you tell me why.)

I have an android application which requires me start multiple threads originating from various classes and only advance to the next activity once all threads have done their job. I also want to add a "failsafe" timeout in case one the the threads takes too long (HTTP request taking too long or something.)

I searched Stack Overflow and found a post saying that I should create a class to keep a running total of open threads and then use a timer to poll for when all the threads are completed.

I think I've created a working class to do this for me, it's untested as of yet but has no errors showing in eclipse.

Is this a correct implementation? Are there any APIs that I should be made aware of (such as classes in the Java or Android APIs that could be used in place of the abstract classes at the bottom of the class?)

```
package com.dmp.geofix.libs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ThreadMonitor {

    private Timer timer = null;
    private TimerTask timerTask = null;
    private OnSuccess onSuccess = null;
    private OnError onError = null;

    private static ArrayList<Thread> threads;

    private final int POLL_OPEN_THREADS = 100;
    private final int TIMEOUT = 10000;

    public ThreadMonitor() {
        timerTask = new PollThreadsTask();
    }

    public ThreadMonitor(OnSuccess s) {
        timerTask = new PollThreadsTask();
        onSuccess = s;
    }

    public ThreadMonitor(OnError e) {
        timerTask = new PollThreadsTask();
        onError = e;
    }

    public ThreadMonitor(OnSuccess s, OnError e) {
        timerTask = new PollThreadsTask();
        onSuccess = s;
        onError = e;
    }

    public void start() {
        Iterator<Thread> i = threads.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            i.next().start();
        }

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, POLL_OPEN_THREADS);
    }

    public void finish() {
        Iterator<Thread> i = threads.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            i.next().interrupt();
        }

        threads.clear();
        timer.cancel();
    }

    public void addThread(Thread t) {
        threads.add(t);
    }

    public void removeThread(Thread t) {
        threads.remove(t);
        t.interrupt();
    }

    class PollThreadsTask extends TimerTask {

        private int timeElapsed = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeElapsed += POLL_OPEN_THREADS;
            if (timeElapsed <= TIMEOUT) {
                if (threads.isEmpty() == false) {
                    if (onSuccess != null) {
                        onSuccess.run();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (onError != null) {
                    onError.run();
                }
                finish();
            }
        }

    }

    public abstract class OnSuccess {
        public abstract void run();
    }

    public abstract class OnError {
        public abstract void run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Thread.join](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Check java.util.concurrent package . 
specifically  Future, FutureTask  and ExecutorService
FutureTask allows to get the status of the operation under execution with methid isDone()

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

All the threads should be implementing callable and they should be future tasks.

Start all of them with countdownlatch/CyclicBarrier to ensure all of them start at same time

Comment: Wouldn't implementing callable on all the threads and passing them to FutureTask make them call that code multiple times? I just want to wait for everything to finish and then call a single method, once, with an alternate block of code (for if one of the threads timeout).

Comment: Join can only be used if some threads which finished processing has to wait for remaining threads. How can you check timeout thing for the other threads.

Comment: Join can only be used if some threads which finished processing has to wait for remaining threads. How can you check timeout thing for the other threads. Add one more thread which acts as a monitor thread to check whether threads are still processing. Cancel that tasks which are running out of time. Adding of countdown latch guarantees that all tasks are started at the same time

Answer (score 1):

If you intend for the application to exit after running the code, you might want to have a look at Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread) to specify a thread to be executed when the application is exiting.

Comment: This is within an android application, as such there would be a "proper" android way of running code when the application exits. Which would be the onPause() and onStop() callback methods in the Activity class.